# How do I avoid a useEffect loop when the dep is a function from a default parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm writing a video component and I've run into a useEffect rendering loop with an event function prop called `onParentNotify`.

```js
function VideoPlayer({
  videoPath = "",
  onNotifyParent = () => null, // <-- this is where the problem is.
}) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
  const videoRef = useRef();

  const isLoading = status?.isLoading;

  useEffect(() => {
   if (!isLoading) {
     onNotifyParent("log has loaded!");
   }
  }, [isLoading, videoPath, onNotifyParent]);

  return (<Video
    ref={videoRef}
    videoPath={videoPath}
    onStatus={(status) => setStatus(status)}
  />)
}
```

I memoized this function in the outer `ParentComponent1` which prevented the loop.

```js
function ParentComponent1() {
  // Yay, works!
  const handleNotifyParent = useCallback((msg = "") => {
    console.log(msg);
  });

   return (<VideoPlayer 
     videoPath="http://video-url-here.com" 
     onNotifyParent={handleNotifyParent}
   >);
}
```

But with `ParentComponent2`, that component doesn't pass the prop, so it defaults to  `onNotifyParent = () => null` in the props declaration for `VideoPlayer`, causing the loop.

```js
// Eeek! Rendering loops ahead
function ParentComponent2() {
   return <VideoPlayer videoPath="http://video-url-here.com">;
}
```

**My question is:** how should I go about memoizing the default prop parameter `onNotifyParent` when the prop is *undefined*? Two solutions come to mind, but they seem a bit clunky:

1. Define default function outside the component scope.

```js
const DEFAULT_FUNC = () => null;

function VideoPlayer({
  videoPath = "",
  onNotifyParent = DEFAULT_FUNC, // ew
  onSomethingElse = DEFAULT_FUNC,
  onAnotherThing = DEFAULT_FUNC,
}) { 
  // ... 
}
```

2. Pass null as the default and call the function conditionally.

```js
function VideoPlayer({
  videoPath = "",
  onNotifyParent = null
}) { 
  useEffect(() => {
   if (!isLoading) {
     onNotifyParent?.("log has loaded!"); // feels wrong...
   }
  }, [isLoading, videoPath, onNotifyParent]);
}
```

Or is there a better/different convention to follow in this case?

Comment: Both solutions you proposed are totally fine.

Comment: A third approach that could sometimes be useful would be `const notify = onNotifyParent ?? () => null; notify("log has loaded!")` inside the effect function, but in your case that comes down to being a long-winded variation of the nullish-coalescing call..

Comment: Option #1 FTW. My advice in general is to define as few functions as possible within your components

Comment: Like @Bergi said, both your solutions are acceptable and likely to pass code-review. In reply to `ew` and `// feels wrong...`, why do you feel your proposed solutions are wrong?

Comment: @vighnesh153 I feel like #1 ends up littering the global scope just  to circumvent a React behavior and #2 ends up being less explicit in what the prop is expecting. Plus I have to remember to nullish-coalesce each time, which adds mental overhead.

Comment: @JCraine why would it be global scope? Define it in the same module as your component. If you don't export it, nothing else will even see it. That being said, I often find it handy to have an `export const noop = () => {}` utility function

Comment: In react, all your files would be modules. So, it is not polluting your global scope unless you explicitly use `window.` or `var` (in some cases). It will just be global to that file

Comment: Sorry, I meant module scope not global.

Comment: If you add Typescript and Eslint, you will be reminded to add null coalescing by TS and ESlint and you won't need to remember. This pattern is quite common.

Comment: @vighnesh153 I was wondering about TypeScript, would a TS solution end up being closer to #1? Eg, where the defaults are declared outside?

Comment: In TS, your components would have clearly defined prop types (now that I think about it, you can use `prop-types` without needing to integrating TS). That way, if you have a prop which has a type `Function | null`, and you invoke directly `Function()`, TS will complain at compile/build time. This way, you won't miss adding null coalescing. Declaring defaults for props within or outside the component is your choice regardless of whether you use TS or not.

Comment: @vighnesh153 Thanks for the tip! I wasn't aware of prop-types as a feature of React, reading more about it now.

Comment: Assuming your posted code is just an example and that I don't really know what you want to do with onNotifyParent, I'm wondering if onNotifyParent needs to be defined (or not) for each parent component. Could onNotifyParent benefit from being custom hook called in VideoPlayer which takes appropriate actions based on props being passed in to it?

Comment: @shawncaza Possibly, although in my case the parent component needs to change its background appearance based on the child videoplayer's state. Not sure that would be possible to do without Context (which I want to avoid for simplicity's sake).

Comment: Can you keep track of the background appearance in a useState variable? Pass the setState function to the child.

Comment: I think it would end up being the same, since `onNotifyParent` has the setState call inside itself.
Interestingly, I found that passing the setter as a prop directly requires it be in the child's useEffect dependency array - despite setters being stable (and omittable) when inside the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the discussion here, I've decided to go with **option #2** - passing null as the default and calling the function conditionally with null coalescing:

```js
function VideoPlayer({
  videoPath = "",
  onNotifyParent = null, // <-- here
}) { 
  useEffect(() => {
   if (!isLoading) {
     onNotifyParent?.("log has loaded!"); // <-- and here
   }
  }, [isLoading, videoPath, onNotifyParent]);
}
```

In future I may turn to TypeScript or [React prop-types](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and end up with a solution that resembles option #1, but for the time being I'm just going to keep things simple and avoid setting default parameter functions. Thanks all for your time today.